# Avoding combinatorial explosion with multiple one-to-many joins?

Tags: oracle, query-performance

To explain I have a "compound" entity and each compound can have one or more lots. Each lot can have 0 to multiple measurements of each measurement type. There are many measurement type each with it's own table and different columns.

The query I need to build must return all data for any compound that matches all the filters. If say lot 1 of compound B matches "filter 1"  and lot 3 of compound B matches "filter 2",then I should return all data for that compound, so all lots.

In essence this means I have to do a inner join from compound to measurement for each measurement type. If I join on lot level, then the query will not return lots that don't match the filters.

The inner join on compound level leads to combinatorial explosion which can make queries run very slow as instead of returning like 100 results it's millions of rows.

I can't change the data structure. I have to deal with what exists.

I'm looking for a general strategy and advice how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help. It sounds like you might want an `EXISTS` or some form of aggregation.